# Disabling utf-8 in all terminals?

Tags: terminal, character-encoding, ascii

This question pertains to my Ubuntu 18 system, as follows ...

```
% uname -a
Linux myhost.name.net 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I don't know how long the following has been going on in the midst of my regular system upgrades, but I have now noticed that all my terminal windows are writing `UTF-8` characters. I want all terminal windows to use `us.ascii` (or possibly `iso-8859-1`). I can't find anywhere where this is set.

Furthermore, all keyboard input seems to be coming in as `UTF-8`, and I also want it to be `us.ascii` or `iso-8859-1`.

By default, the `LANG` variable is set to `en_US.UTF-8` in all shells that run in my terminal windows, but I am not knowingly setting it that way within any config files.

This occurs under `xterm`, `rxvt`, and `urxvt`, and none of these programs are configured to utilize `UTF-8`, that I know of.

I'm running `XFCE4`, if that makes any difference. I can't find any settings for this in the `XFCE4` settings, either.

Can anyone suggest a way to reset my system so that all terminal windows always display `us.ascii` or `iso-8859-1`, and all keyboard input is also `us.ascii` or `iso-8859-1`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "my terminal windows are writing `UTF-8` characters" – Could you please elaborate on this?

Linux systems have been using `UTF-8` by default for about 10–15 years now. `us.ascii` is a subset of that, if you only use the very basic English letters and symbols present in the US keyboard then `UTF-8` should be just as good for you. There is no encoding called `iso-8859`, there are multiple incompatible ones called `iso-8859-1`, `iso-8859-2` and so on. Which one would you need, and for what? What is the actual problem you're running into?

Comment: I meant `iso-8859-1`. I will correct above in a moment. The problem is that when I copy text from my terminal and try to paste it elsewhere, special characters such as apostrophe and double quote are showing up as multibyte sequences. I want them to show up as single bytes within the 7-bit ascii range. In other words, I want to force the us.ascii subset of utf-8

Comment: Where are you seeing this? us-ascii is a strict subset of both UTF-8 and all of the iso-8859-x. The characters you mention symmetric-double-quote, and apostrophe, are part of us-ascii, and a single byte in utf-8 (same encoding as us-ascii). Most Unixes have been using utf-8 for at least 10 years. Can you show us what is going wrong. This could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157037).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't finding any specific settings because the overwhelming majority of modern Linux software decides the character set to be used by the locale environment variables. Use the `locale` command to view the full set of current locale settings.

Have you checked `/etc/default/locale`? It is the standard Debian configuration file for setting the system default locale. If you want to use iso-8859-1 instead of UTF-8, you should:

- make sure that the `en_US ISO-8859-1` line is uncommented in `/etc/locale.gen` and run `sudo locale-gen` after editing the file if it wasn't
- specify the `LANG` locale variable (or at least `LC_CTYPE`) as `en_US.iso88591` (or whatever is the correct form according to `locale -a | grep en_US`)

If the problem is that you're connecting from your Ubuntu 18 UTF-8 system to legacy systems that use ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8, you might consider inserting a character mapping layer on your outgoing connections instead of downgrading your entire system to deal with the legacy encoding. Make a tiny script (or a shell function) like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
luit -encoding 'ISO 8859-1' ssh "$@"
```

(If you want to enforce strict US-ASCII for the remote endpoint, replace `ISO 8859-1` with `ASCII`.)

Name it whatever you want. Use this script/function instead of the regular `ssh` command when connecting to the systems using legacy character encoding.